# GRE and QEMU and TAP

Tags: qemu, gre

HOST SERVER

```
ENO2 has Internal IP 192.168.55.128 and External IP 200.100.100.100
TAP0 has Internal IP 192.168.10.1
GRE1 has Internal IP 10.10.4.243 and External IP 165.100.100.100
```

VM SERVER

```
eth1 has Internal IP 192.168.10.243
```

when I run vm with

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -smp 4 -m 2G -drive file=disk.qcow2,format=qcow2 -vnc :0 -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no
```

and add iptables nat like

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.243 ! -d 192.168.10.243 -j SNAT --to 192.168.55.128
```

Inside vm ping to 1.1.1.1 works, but after adding below rule

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.243 ! -d 192.168.10.243 -j SNAT --to 10.10.4.243
```

It doesn't work

I even tried using ip route like

```
ip rule add from 192.168.10.243/32 table 123
ip route add default via 192.168.10.243 table 123
```

but it doesn't work

please help